# List navigation - aligning to left and right

Tags: html, css

This is an example markup:

```
<ul id="subnav" class="right">
    <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Note</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I get the "Test" to align to the right of the subnav and the rest of the items to the left? Do I need to have another UL and align that to the right and put test in it, or do I just align the test li to the right?

This is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RbHN5/2/

If anyone could tell me the correct implementation I would appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `float: right` to align the `last-child` alone to right.

```
#subnav li:last-child{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px; /* Optional setting dependent on other styles */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/RbHN5/4/)

**Note:** This works only if the element in question is the `last-child`. If there are multiple elements then the same float setting can be used but with a class as selector (like `.right`) instead of `last-child`.

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/RbHN5/22/) - With multiple right aligned elements using the `right` class.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, what about if I want to be able to put an unlimited number to the left or right? Should I put a left / right float class on the ones I want?

Comment: change the order of the html

Comment: Instead of adding margin-right to the last `li`, it may be better to give `#subnav` the style `box-sizing: border-box`.

Comment: @JamesWillson: When you float right it always goes in the reverse order because the first element is aligned right and the next to the left side of it.

Comment: @RyanMitchell: Yes changing the `box-sizing` is enough but actually `margin-right` is optional depending on other style settings. If you see James' other fiddle, it is not really needed.

Comment: I would suggest you to make a new ul element and float it to right of position it as per the need. Floating each element to right would definitely reverse the order.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can do like this

```
.test
 {
float:right;
margin-right:40px !important;

 }

<li  class="test"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RbHN5/13/

Answer (score 0):

Either you can do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RbHN5/23/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="subnav" class="right">
    <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Note</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;border:none;list-style:none;}
.test{float:right;margin: 20px;}
#subnav {margin: 20px; font-family: Arial;font-size: 13px;}
#subnav li{float:left;border-radius: 4px;line-height: 40px; height: 40px; background-color: white; margin-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;}
#subnav li:last-child{float:right;}
body {background: pink;}
```

.

```
OR
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/RbHN5/19/)

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul id="subnav" class="right">
        <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Note</a></li>    
    </ul>
    <div class="test">
        <a href="#">Test</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{padding:0;margin:0;list-style:none;}
.wrap{position:relative;}
#subnav {margin: 20px; font-family: Arial;
font-size: 13px; width: 100%}
#subnav li{display:inline-block;}
#subnav li, .test{border-radius: 4px;line-height: 40px; height: 40px; background-color: white; margin-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;}
.test{position:absolute;top:0;right:0;}
body {background: pink;}
```

Comment: Absolute positioning would require more tweaking if the need is for more than one element to be aligned right.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is how I would write it:
On the html file,

<ul id="subnav" >
    <li class="left"><a href="#">Email</a></li>
    <li class="left"><a href="#">Note</a></li>
    <li class="right"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
</ul>

And on the CSS file,

#subnav{
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    color:blue;
    background:silver;
    padding:5px;
}
.right{
    float:right;
    margin-left:40px;
}
.left{
    float:left;
}
```